# Is there a problem connecting to archive.ubuntu.com?

Tags: 11.10, software-center, connection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix 'Check your Internet connection' error in software center?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77487/how-to-fix-check-your-internet-connection-error-in-software-center)

I was able to use software center until 2 days ago, but I can't use it for two days. I also tried downloading software using terminal, but it gives a connection error saying to check internet connectins. But I have no problem with my internet connection. Does anyone know something about this?

Answer (score 2):

You have given very little useful information: which server are you using (because archive.ubuntu.com itself is up as you can see by typing this into the adressbar of your browser)? How did you try downloading with the terminal?

Nevertheless: you could try the following:
Open software center; go to 'Edit'->'Software Soures...', click on the selection menu of 'Download from' and choose: 'other'. Then click on best server.

If you had a server that is not reachable, this should give you a working one.

Comment: I am using 11.10. I changed the download source as you said and now I can install programs from software center. But I can't still go to archive.ubuntu.com by even typing it into adressbar.

Comment: So clicking on [this](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/Release) gives you an error?